# Problems creating a component and and importing files using TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, urbancode

I'm trying to use IBM UrbanCode Deploy and TFS to create a new component for an Application. I am having trouble importing the files from the server to Udeploy (**Versions -> Import New Versions**). This error shows whenever I try to get the new version of the component:

*Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client*

I have checked that the agent has .Net framework 3.5 installed.
How can I resolve this error, or is there another way where I can deploy files from tfs to IBM UrbanCode Deploy.

Comment: Looks lik ethe TFS Client Object Model is not installed. Plus, every recent version of the TFS Client Object Model requires .NET 4.5 or 4.6 to be installed.

Comment: You're right, it seems like TFS is not installed on the agent computer. However, I lack the means of installing it myself. I guess I'll have to find another means to do it.

Comment: @Informat If you got  the solution, you could share it  here.

Comment: The problem really was that in the end the agent computer did not have TFS installed. The problem would be resolved by finding an agent with TFS installed or installing it onto the agent you have.